# Fullscreen mode in Adobe Air application, but with no window or title bar

Tags: air, fullscreen

What I want is to run my application in fullscreen mode, but without Windows window, title bar or anything else - just the content that I have created. I tried

`stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

which works, but I can't get rid of the window and the title bar.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [NativeWindowInitOptions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html) class with which you decide what type of window would you like to create (chromeless, transprarent, normal,...).

Or you can set value of systemChrome to none in your **app descriptor xml** file:
...
<!-- The type of system chrome to use (either "standard" or "none"). Optional. Default standard. -->
        <systemChrome>**none**</systemChrome>

...

note, that the later option will apply only for the main application window.